# dates are not sorted correctly in mui-datatables

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, date, mui-datatable

I have dates made & formatted by momentjs e.g. ("Sat, Feb 22, 2020 12:55 PM")
I read them in from firestore, they appear to come in fine as I sort them first to be sorted descending.

```
forms.sort(function(left, right) {
  return moment.utc(left.timeIn).diff(moment.utc(right.timeIn));
});
```

Then I do a console.log to check there are all there and sorted correctly.

Next, I pass them into the Record Table component which contains a mui-datatable.
At this point, problems start to happen.

```
{
  forms.length > 0 ? (
    <RecordTable forms={forms} />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <h2>No Records</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

1. they do not display on screen sorted descending with most recent date at the top.

   ```
   {
     name: "timeIn",
     label: "Time In",
     options: {
       sortDirection: "desc",
       searchable: false
     }
   },
   ```

[image]

2. for some reason likely my fault, the values passed into the mui-datatable come in 100's of times even though there are only 75 records. I can see this by doing first doing a console log in the child component then another console.log within mui-datatables on one of the columns which has a customBody Render.

I am really not sure what I am doing wrong here, as the dates are sorted before they are passed to mui-datatables, and from console logs in the parent component, only 75 records are printed out as oppose to hundreds in mui-data table console.logs

Comment: When you pass a non–standard string to moment.js without providing the format, it uses the built–in parser so you might as well just do `return new Date(left.timeIn) - new Date(right.timeIn)`, which will be more efficient. Also, when proving sample data, please provide it as text as otherwise those who wish to help must first transcribe your image to code. That is a considerable hurdle to those who might wish to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving a format to the Date of "YYYY-MM-DD"

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have since switched to React Table.